# Java checksum calculation for serial comunication

Tags: java, checksum

I have this code in Java:

```
public static synchronized String generarCheckSum(int campoInicio, String comando, boolean tieneCheckSum)
{
    String checkSum = "";
    int leerHasta = 1;
    if(tieneCheckSum)
        leerHasta = 3;
    int suma = campoInicio;
    int idxInicio = 0;
    try
    {
        if(!es3600(comando))
        {
            idxInicio = 1;
            for(int i = 0; i < TIPO_EQUIPO.length; i++)
                if(TIPO_EQUIPO[i].equals(comando.substring(0, 1)))
                    suma = suma + 65 + i;

        }
        for(int i = idxInicio; i <= comando.length() - leerHasta; i++)
        {
            if(comando.charAt(i) == '\n')
                continue;
            if(comando.charAt(i) == '\u20AC')
                suma += 128;
            else
                suma += comando.charAt(i);
        }

        String sumaStr = Integer.toHexString(suma);
        sumaStr = sumaStr.substring(sumaStr.length() - 2, sumaStr.length());
        String Eh = (new StringBuilder()).append("3").append(sumaStr.charAt(0)).toString();
        String El = (new StringBuilder()).append("3").append(sumaStr.charAt(1)).toString();
        checkSum = (new StringBuilder()).append(UtlGeneral.convertirHexaToASCII(Eh)).append(UtlGeneral.convertirHexaToASCII(El)).toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return checkSum;
}
```

It is called like this for example:

```
chk = generarCheckSum(2, comando, false)
```

I do not know Java, so I am having a hard time understanding what the code does. From what I can understand it is calculating a two byte checksum from a string.

I have this examples of strings in hex:

```
07303131393904
07303232393B04
07303332393C04
073235323A3004
```

In this lines, the only thing that changes is the equipment number: 01, 02, 03 and 25

I am guessing the first and last byte are delimiters: 07 and 04, and that 3939, 393B, 393C and 3A30 are the calculated checksums.

The es3600 check returns TRUE in my case, since the equipment is a 3600 model.

What is the algorithm for the checksum calculation?

EDIT: MORE INFO.

In this other sample:

```
02 30 33 33 34 30 33 30 32 30 31 30 34 30 35 30 36 32 31 04
```

Adding all the numbers = 321 (hex) so the result is 32 31 (just using the last 2 digits of 321) Very strange way to do a checksum...

Comment: If `s` is a string, `s.charAt(n)` returns the `n`'th character, starting at 0, i.e. `s.charAt(0)` is the first character, `s.charAt(1)` is the second character, etc.  `s.substring(0,1)` returns a `String` whose length is 1 character, using the same character as `s.charAt(0)`.  `Eh` and `El` basically get set to 2-character strings whose first character is `'3'`.  The last line that assigns to `sumaStr` assigns it to the last two characters of the previous `sumaStr`.

Comment: I more or less understood that. It seems that adding "charAt" add the ascii hex value of the character to suma.

Comment: I more or less got what is doing, I think they are calculating a checksum in a very convoluted way: The hex values of each character are being added, INCLUDING the first character. For example the first line is 07+30+31+31 = 99 and it gets converted to 3939 If the string is longer and the sum is greater that FF, they use the last 2 characters of the hex number, and do the split and add the two "3"s. Very strange how they are calculating this.

Comment: Right, in this context Java's `char` type is treated as an integer (so that the character `'A'` is equivalent to the integer 65 = `0x41`, etc.).

Comment: `charAt` gives the numeric value of each character, not the hex value (it's a number, not a string), and it is the UTF-16BE value, not ASCII, although for all characters which are not Unicode high half or low half surrogates it will be the same as the Unicode code point, and Latin-1 is a subset of Unicode, and ASCII is a subset of Latin-1.

Comment: ajb: If you post you comment as an answer I will accept that, since you got me started. David: thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came with (This is Visual FoxPro) (Yes, I know)

```
*!* GENERARCHECKSUM

Lparameters pString

Local checksum, lnx

m.checksum = 0

For m.lnx = 1 To Len(m.pString)
    m.checksum = m.checksum + Asc(Substr(m.pString, m.lnx, 1))
Endfor

Return Chr(0x30 + Bitrshift(Bitand(m.checksum, 0xf0), 4)) + Chr(0x30 + Bitand(m.checksum, 0x0f))
```